# Link lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hey guys, sorry for, but I'm new to doubly-linked lists and was wondering if anyone could tell me why my program crashes when i use add_end()?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 node *start_ptr = NULL;
 node *current;
 int option = 0;

 void add_end()
 {
     node *temp, *temp2;
     temp = new node;
     cout << "Enter name: ";
     cin >> temp->name;
     cout << "Enter profession: ";
     cin >> temp->profession;
     cout << "Enter age: ";
     cin >> temp->age;
     temp->nxt = NULL;
     if (start_ptr = NULL)
     {
     start_ptr = temp;
     current = start_ptr;
     }
     else
     {
         temp2 = start_ptr;
         while (temp2->nxt != NULL)
         {
            temp2 = temp2->nxt;
         }
         temp2->nxt = temp;
         temp->prv = temp2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where is `node` defined? Any reason in particular you're not using `std::list` (or even better `std::vector`)?

Comment: One likely error:  if "(start_ptr = NULL)" sets start_ptr to NULL.  I think you meant "if (start_ptr == NULL)"

Comment: Without seeing how this function is being called, and without knowing what specifically a *crash* is, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet that this `if ( start_ptr = NULL )` is not what you intended... Did you forget an `=`? The if condition will never be met, as that statement is equivalent to `start_ptr = 0; if (0)`, and then your code will assume that `start_ptr` can be dereferenced. You assing it to `temp2` and then dereference `NULL` to access `static_cast<node*>(0)->next`...

Answer (score 0):

This line is obviously wrong:

```
if (start_ptr = NULL)
```